# Can we say that the composition $ST$ or $TS$ is not compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S$ and $T$ be two bounded linear operator defined on Hilbert space $H$. Assume that $S$ and $T$ are not compact operators. Can we say that the composition $ST$ or $TS$ is not compact?

My example is that let $L$ be left shift operator defined on $\ell_2$ and $R$ be right shift operator. Then they are bounded but not compact. Note that $LR=I$ is not compact. Also, $RL(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=(0,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ is not compact (for example taking $e_n$, we can show that $\{RL(e_n)\}$ is not Cauchy subsequent.

But can we prove the above general result? I know that we have the ideal property of compact operator: if $S$ is bounded and $T$ is compact, then $TS$ and $ST$ are both compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two infinite dimensional subspaces such that $$\langle x,y\rangle =0\hspace{5mm}\forall x\in H_1\hspace{3mm}\forall y\in H_2. $$ Let $P_j:H\to H_j$ be orthogonal projections. Then, $P_1P_2 = 0 = P_2P_1$. Neither projection is compact.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little bit confused. What have you proved? It seems that is not what I want to ask?

Comment: @H.YDuan Product of 2 non-compact operators can be compact (zero map $0:H\to H$ is compact).